# Duplicate Questions

Tags: discussion

I'm starting to see a good deal of duplicate questions. How are we handling that? Is there a way we can redirect duplicate asks to the original question easily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this help center article](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) — it explains why certain questions are closed as duplicates of others, and how to do that.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!